# LESS li class not working

Tags: html, css, less

I'm using this code in my LESS file, the &:hover is working correctly but the .active is not working.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this ?

```
    li{
      padding: 8% 10%;
      list-style-type: none;
      li.active,
      &:hover{
        background-color: #e33939;
        color: #fff;
      }
      a{
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Change the `li.active` to `&.active` unless you are targetting a child `li` tag.

Comment: Just check have you included the `less-1.3.0.min.js` in your project.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select `li` elements that have `active` class name you should use the `&` otherwise your selector is compiled as a [descendant combinator selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/descendant) (`li li.active`) that selects descendant `li.active` elements of `li` elements.

```
li {
      padding: 8% 10%;
      list-style-type: none;
      &.active,
      &:hover{
        background-color: #e33939;
        color: #fff;
      }
      ...
}
```

This is the compiled CSS:

```
li {
  padding: 8% 10%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.active,
li:hover {
  background-color: #e33939;
  color: #fff;
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
li{
      padding: 8% 10%;
      list-style-type: none;
      &.active,
      &:hover{
        background-color: #e33939;
        color: #fff;
      }
      a{
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
```